# Is there such a thing as a const constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Today I accidentally put `const` at the beginning of my constructor (copy paste mistake) and it compiled. I've only tried this in Visual Studio 2008 which is pre C++11. Does this syntax have any meaning? Is this Microsoft's early attempts at `constexpr`?

```
class foo
{
public:
    const foo(int i){}
};

foo f(1);
```

Comment: I wonder what affect it has, if any, in VC++08. It might just be .. ignored?

Comment: I was able to call non-const functions in the body of the constructor so, if it has an effect, it's not restricting what is called in the constructor.

Comment: @cppguy that's not so surprising, since the ctor is not declared as `foo(int i) const`. I wonder if the latter works in VS (with a mutable member variable), although ctors can not be cv-qualified :)

Comment: "error C2583: 'foo::foo' : 'const' 'this' pointer is illegal for constructors/destructors... seems not

Comment: @cppguy yes, that should indeed be the case. Have to say that the reasons for accepting non-standard `const` in front of the ctor is completely elusive for me.

Comment: I'd guess that since it has no effect, the compiler writers found it easier to not disallow it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not standard compliant, there is no such thing. However, starting with C++11, you can have `constexpr` constructors, so your object is constructed at compile time and can further be used in `constexpr` expressions.

Although I am not using it, MSVS is not the best compiler in terms of standard-compliance, at least that's what I realized from various questions on this site.